# How to fix this screen to scroll down in React Native, because I cant?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I`m trying to render the Header and HomePage in App with scrollView, i can't scroll till the end of page and see all the content.

I have tried `<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>`

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contentContainer: {
    flexGrow:1,
  }
});
```

This is my App file

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:"#f9f9f9"}}>
      <Header />
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
      <HomePage/>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
    );
}

 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contentContainer: {
    flexGrow:1,
  }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Try to add `marginBottom: 10` inside Home Page component View.

Comment: Thanks for response but is not working, is there anything else I can do? Is seems like ScrollView is not responding at all.

Comment: add paddingBottom:10 in contentContainer

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, I can't see whole context, header should have fixed height, flex won't work inside of scrollView

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor:"#f9f9f9"}}>
        <Header /> 
        <ScrollView style={{ height: '100%'}}>
          <HomePage/>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
```